# Script bash - Subir directorio comprimido a un ftp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, shell-script

tengo un servidor en linux con un sistema de copias mysql rotacional y me mantienen los 30 ultimos dias, dejando esta estructura de carpetas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el script que estoy montando para subir los ficheros a un ftp externo es este

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='ftp.ejemplo.com'
USER='root'
PASSWD='mipassword'
DIA=`date +"%d%m%Y_%H%M"`
   
cd /tmp
rm -fr copia
mkdir copia
cd copia


export GZIP=-9
tar -czvf $DIA-mysql.tar.gz  /root/backups/mysql


FILE=$DIA-mysql.tar.gz

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
binary
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Este script lo que hace es comprimir el directorio donde tengo "todas" las copias de mysql /root/backups/mysql y lo comprime en /tmp/copia

Y luego lo sube a un ftp, hasta este punto funcina todo correctamente.

Lo que me faltaria por hacer y no se como hacerlo, es en el momento de comprimir la carpeta /root/backups/mysql que solo coja el directorio más NUEVO y descarte los viejos.

Gracias,

Comment: muy buen trabajo! ¿Has considerado usar logrotate para hacer esta rotación? En cuanto a coger el último en sí, ¿no podrías generar el nombre dinámicamente a partir del día actual? La alternativa sería ordenar por tiempo y coger el último, pero implica parsear cosas que pueden ser algo frágiles

Answer (score 0):

Publico la respuesta, gracias a las respuestas de los compañeros pude completar el script.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='xxx'
USER='xxx'
PASSWD='xxx'
DIA=`date +"%d%m%Y_%H%M"`

cd /tmp
rm -fr copia
mkdir copia
cd copia


DIA=`date +"%d%m%Y_%H%M"`

cd /tmp
rm -fr copia
mkdir copia
cd copia

export GZIP=-9

tar -czvf $DIA-deploys.tar.gz --exclude="*/vendor/*" --exclude="*/.git/*" --exclude="*/node_modules/*" /var/www/html


FILE=$DIA-deploys.tar.gz

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
binary
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Comment: si me permites una sugerencia, cambia el formato de la fecha, y pon primero año-mes-dia. Asi lo tendras ordenado, y luego con 'sort' y 'head' puedes obtener el primero/ultimo (segun te interese)

Comment: sugiero no usar nombres con mayúscula, pues pueden liarse con las variables de entorno. También, sería bueno añadir comentarios, así como usar `$()` para ejecutar cosas en lugar de los backticks. Entiendo que la solución ha sido usar `FILE=$DIA-deploys.tar.gz`.